# Bootstrap free template license?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use this free template from startbootstrap (http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) in my work for commercial use. I read the license and not quite sure if I am allowed. Is there any specific disclosure I need to be able to use this template for commercial use?

> The License
>
> 2. Grant of Copyright License. Subject to the terms and conditions of
>        this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual,
>        worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable
>        copyright license to reproduce, prepare Derivative Works of,
>        publicly display, publicly perform, sublicense, and distribute the
>        Work and such Derivative Works in Source or Object form.
> 3. Grant of Patent License. Subject to the terms and conditions of
>        this License, each Contributor hereby grants to You a perpetual,
>        worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable
>        (except as stated in this section) patent license to make, have made,
>        use, offer to sell, sell, import, and otherwise transfer the Work,
>        where such license applies only to those patent claims licensable
>        by such Contributor that are necessarily infringed by their
>        Contribution(s) alone or by combination of their Contribution(s)
>        with the Work to which such Contribution(s) was submitted. If You
>        institute patent litigation against any entity (including a
>        cross-claim or counterclaim in a lawsuit) alleging that the Work
>        or a Contribution incorporated within the Work constitutes direct
>        or contributory patent infringement, then any patent licenses
>        granted to You under this License for that Work shall terminate
>        as of the date such litigation is filed.

Comment: This is off topic because this we are not lawyers and cannot offer lefal advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking legal advice.

Comment: Off-topic. It's a licensing/legal question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

the part that states:

> grants to You a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge, royalty-free, irrevocable (except as stated in this section) patent license to make, have made, use, offer to sell, sell, import, and otherwise transfer the Work,

states that you are free to use, offer to sell, sell, import, and otherwise transfer the Work so yes, you will be allowed to use this for commercial work.

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer and do not claim to be an expert in copy write laws so do not quote me on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it for any purpose because javascripts are under MIT or BSD licence. You can always distribute this source code on demand. And with MIT or Creative common license you are prohibbited delete author from them. But you are allowed to distribute and modify this source code without violate this license.

so don't worry :) and enjoy it